# Running a nested while loop inside a foreach loop in Perl

Tags: perl, loops

I'm trying to use a `foreach` loop to loop through an array and then use a nested `while` loop to loop through each line of a text file to see if the array element matches a line of text; if so then I push data from that line into a new array to perform calculations.

The outer `foreach` loop appears to be working correctly (based on printed results with each array element) but the inner while loop is not looping (same data pushed into array each time).

Any advice?

The code is below

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -T

use CGI qw(:cgi-lib :standard);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $input       = param('sequence');
my $meanexpfile = "final_expression_complete.txt";

open(FILE, $meanexpfile) or print "unable to open file";

my @meanmatches;

@regex = (split /\s/, $input);

foreach $regex (@regex) {

    while (my $line = <FILE>) {
        if ( $line =~ m/$regex\s(.+\n)/i ) {
            push(@meanmatches, $1);
        }
    }

    my $average                  = average(@meanmatches);
    my $std_dev                  = std_dev($average, @meanmatches);
    my $average_round            = sprintf("%0.4f", $average);
    my $stdev_round              = sprintf("%0.4f", $std_dev);
    my $coefficient_of_variation = $stdev_round / $average_round;
    my $cv_round                 = sprintf("%0.4f", $coefficient_of_variation);

    print font(
        { color => "blue" }, "<br><B>$regex average: $average_round   
&nbspStandard deviation: $stdev_round&nbspCoefficient of 
variation(Cv): $cv_round</B>"
    );
}

sub average {
    my (@values) = @_;
    my $count    = scalar @values;
    my $total    = 0;

    $total += $_ for @values;

    return $count ? $total / $count : 0;
}

sub std_dev {
    my ($average, @values) = @_;
    my $count       = scalar @values;
    my $std_dev_sum = 0;

    $std_dev_sum += ($_ - $average)**2 for @values;

    return $count ? sqrt($std_dev_sum / $count) : 0;
}
```

Comment: The way you calculate the [averages is flawed](http://www.nu42.com/2015/03/how-you-average-numbers.html), and your standard deviation is going to fail catastrophically. See [Algorithms for calculating variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance). While you are at it, you probably want the unbiased standard deviation estimator.

Comment: Also, where is this CGI script running? It seems to me anyone who can invoke this script can do interesting things with it.

Comment: I have laid out your Perl code so that it is more readable. It is *essential* that you do that yourself so that you can spot any scoping problems, and it is only polite to post readable code when you are hoping for help to debug it. For the same reasons you *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program that you write. They are invaluable aids to finding problems with your code, and without `use strict` there is little point in using `my` to declare anything. In this case, `use strict` reveals that you have failed to declare either `@regex` or `$regex`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Your blog post is fascinating. I have often used something similar to calculate rolling statistics, but had no thought that the accuracy would be improved. (I might have known that Don Knuth was involved.) But I think you overstate the importance of doing things "properly". As you say yourself, *"One saving grace of the real world is the fact that a given variable is unlikely to contain values with such an extreme range"* and I hope it would be apparent to anyone who had to write for such an unusual data set that special methods were necessary.

Comment: @Borodin Did you try the variance experiment at the end? That is small set of numbers that are close to each other. One must resort to somewhat contrived examples to illustrate the problem in one step, but in real life, you tend to do a lot more summations. It is important to calculate things stably.

Comment: @Borodin Regarding this question, note that the thing that *really* turns me off is the fact that a CGI script takes user input and uses it willy nilly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, my advice would be:

- Turn on `strict` and `warnings`.
- perltidy your code,
- use 3 argument open: `open ( my $inputfile, "<", 'final_expression.txt' );`
- `die` if it doesn't open - the rest of your program is irrelevant.
- `chomp $line`
- you are iterating your filehandle, but once you've done this you're at the end of file for the next iteration of the `foreach` loop so your `while` loops becomes a null operation. Simplistically, reading the file into an array `my @lines = <FILE>;` would fix this.

So with that in mind:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:cgi-lib :standard);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $input       = param('sequence');
my $meanexpfile = "final_expression_complete.txt";
open( my $input_file, "<", $meanexpfile ) or die "unable to open file";
my @meanmatches;

my @regex = ( split /\s/, $input );
my @lines = <$input_file>;
chomp (@lines);
close($input_file) or warn $!;

foreach my $regex (@regex) {
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        if ( $line =~ m/$regex\s(.+\n)/i ) {
            push( @meanmatches, $1 );
        }
    }

    my $average                  = average(@meanmatches);
    my $std_dev                  = std_dev( $average, @meanmatches );
    my $average_round            = sprintf( "%0.4f", $average );
    my $stdev_round              = sprintf( "%0.4f", $std_dev );
    my $coefficient_of_variation = $stdev_round / $average_round;
    my $cv_round = sprintf( "%0.4f", $coefficient_of_variation );

    print font(
        { color => "blue" }, "<br><B>$regex average: $average_round   
&nbspStandard deviation: $stdev_round&nbspCoefficient of 
variation(Cv): $cv_round</B>"
    );
}

sub average {
    my (@values) = @_;
    my $count    = scalar @values;
    my $total    = 0;
    $total += $_ for @values;

    return $count ? $total / $count : 0;
}

sub std_dev {
    my ( $average, @values ) = @_;

    my $count       = scalar @values;
    my $std_dev_sum = 0;
    $std_dev_sum += ( $_ - $average )**2 for @values;

    return $count ? sqrt( $std_dev_sum / $count ) : 0;
}
```

Comment: Believe it or not, my first draft had that, but I lost it again :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that starting from the second iteration of foreach you are trying to read from already read file handle. You need to rewind to the beginning to read it again:

```
foreach $regex (@regex) {
    seek FILE, 0, 0;
    while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
```

However that does not look very performant. Why read file several times at all, when you can read it once before the foreach starts, and then iterate through the list:

```
my @lines;
while (<FILE>) {
    push (@lines, $_);
}

foreach $regex (@regex) {
    foreach $line (@lines) {
```

Having the latter, you might also what to consider using `grep` instead of the `while` loop.

Comment: If all you're doing is `push`ing the lines onto an array, you can drop the `while` loop and simply do `my @lines = <FILE>;` Don't forget to `chomp`!